Не находит функции с z_ префиксом Zlib при сборке Makefiles
Я сделал форк чата https://github.com/impomezia/schat
Добавил поиск по подключённым к каналу.
Пытаюсь собрать под WSL ubuntu-22.04 и возникают проблемы при сборке.
Мои шаги:

apt-get update && apt-get upgrade и зависимости qt5 + multimedia + webkit
cd /root
git clone https://github.com/ShestakovAndrew/schat
qmake -r
make


Посмотрел через ldd, там при сборке подсоединяется системный /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
Я скачал Zlib 1.2.9 с github и установил его:

./configurate --zprefix
make
Перенёс созданные файлы {libz.a libz.so libz.so.1 libz.so.1.2.9} в /usr/lib/zlib-prefiz/ (с помощью nm убедился что сигнатуры начинаются с z_)
Ошибка возникает при сборке Makefile.schat2-core, который создаётся через qmake schat2-core.pro. В Makefile.schat2-core я добавил следующие строки, чтобы при сборке в libschat.so была моя /usr/lib/zlib-prefiz/libz.so.1:

9.1) Заменяю в переменной LFLAGS -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ на -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/zlib-prefiz/
9.2) Добавляю в переменную LIBS /usr/lib/zlib-prefix/libz.so
При повторной сборке вылезла такая же ошибка. Посмотрел через ldd у файла libschat.so, должен использоваться мой /usr/lib/zlib-prefix/libz.so. Если устанавливаю в систему zlib с z_, то ломается больше, чем чинится)
У меня нет больше идей как это можно починить. Может как-то можно собрать zlib и с z_ и без него в один файл libz.so ?

В начале файла schat2-core.pro добавьте QT_CONFIG += system-zlib.
